# Comparison of t-value and F-value

Tags: anova, t-test, ancova

I have conducted a t-test via SPSS, followed by an ANCOVA (Analysis of Covariance). Now I am wondering if it is correct to report the t-value and then the F-value of the ANCOVA. But are those two values really comparable? Or would I have to run an ANOVA first, instead of a t-test? I know that technically there shouldn't be a difference between the results of a t-test and an one-way ANOVA if I only have two groups, but this really confuses me.

Additionally the criteria of homogeneity of variances isn't met - is there a way to correct that when conducting an ANCOVA?

Comment: Are you including a covariate in your ANCOVA? If you did a t-test and an ANOVA (i.e. with only two groups and no covariate) then $F=t^2$ and the results of the hypothesis test element of the tests (i.e. the p-value) should be equivalent.

Comment: @JamesStanley Thank you! Yes I'm having a covariate in the ANCOVA. But I am still wondering about the second problem: since the F-value I get from the ANCOVA isn't corrected for inhomogeneity of variance it's actually useless to report it, isn't it? Is there an option to chose so I get the corrected value (like in ANOVA the Welch-value)?